# Font-family not showing correctly on my website

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, google-font-api

I am not sure what happened to my css font-family that I was using on my website.  Until yesterday it was working on.  Then this morning it stopped working on Chrome and then later on FireFox & Safari (Mac).

Weird thing is that it looks fine on one of my teammates computer (Linux) but also looks bad on a friend's Mac computer.  No idea what happened.  When I inspect the element I can see the CSS font-family attribute but it is crossed out, as if the font did not load.

This is how I have my fonts added on my CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700|Open+Sans:600italic,400,600,700|Helvetica+Neue:400,500,700);
```

This is [how it looks now](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s68/sh/6148c419-e444-474e-b01b-629994e1716a/c73abc2f8f346bfb74fba14ad6f4b876) and [how it should look](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s68/sh/302cab81-8a88-428f-96ec-0c1926e52cb2/3d07550ebed95c4fcf388f170d156dfd).

Completely stuck, no idea what happened.

Comment: Just a note: the images you linked to say "achivements" instead of "achievements"...

Comment: "CSS font-family attribute but it is crossed out" That probably means the rule is being overridden. What's your CSS? the only code you've posted is the least relevant part.

Comment: @Jon, thanks, just some temporary text, but thanks keeping an eye out buddy

Comment: @AlexWayne, but it worked until yesterday.  And now even if I disable all other fonts, or make this one !important, it is still not styling it with the appropriate font-family.  It seems like the browser is not downloading these fonts (It is happening throughout the site not just for this text. Am I suddenly importing the fonts incorrectly?

Comment: @LuisP Come on man, throw us a bone. How are we supposed to help with only that information? Recreate your problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and post it. Also, are you accessing a page by an `https://` url when it doesn't work, by chance?

Comment: @AlexWayne, sorry, you are absolutely right.  I just got it to work, it seems like it was something to do with the import.  But yes, sorry, I should've added more info and was about to do so before I got it fixed.  Thanks for the quick help and +1...

Comment: I think there's a bug in the Rokkitt font somehow. Experiencing the same problems building a site right now. Characters disappear, especially when using &euro;-like codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the part `|Helvetica+Neue:400,500,700`.

Google Web Fonts do not contain Helvetica Neue. It is a commercial font, not available for free, and probably not available as a web font for a fee either.

When you have a font that does not exist at Google Web Fonts in your requests, the Google server responds with 403 Forbidden and does not send *any* font. You can see this if you use the developer tools (F12) and look at the Network section when loading your page.

When you split your request to three requests, one for each font family, the other requests are successful. But it is more efficient to do have the two font families in one request and drop Helvetica Neue (or replace it with some font that Google actually has).

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it...  Weird that it was working before.  Any suggestion for a free webfont that looks like Helvetica Neue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it to work.  Not sure what happened.  All I did is change the line:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700|Open+Sans:600italic,400,600,700|Helvetica+Neue:400,500,700);
```

to:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600italic,400,600,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica+Neue:400,500,700);
```

Comment: @SurrealDreams, yes, I have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer.  Will do so

Comment: All this does is make 3 requests for the same content instead of one. I have a hunch that it got "fixed" by this change coincidentally. I'll bet you dollar it happens again later.

Comment: @AlexWayne, I know, makes no sense why this would work.  Will update the question (with more content!) if/when it happens.

Comment: @AlexWayne, weird, it seems to be when I add Helvetica+Neue inline with the other fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica Neue is in fact available at Google Fonts:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica+Neue